# Prepopulate AngularJS form with invalid data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My model contains some data that does not passes the form's validation (say an invalid email address that comes from the server). I still want to show this invalid model data to the user so they get a chance to fix it.

Minimal example:

```
  <form ng-init="email='foo'">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email"></input>
  </form>
```

How do I get the input to show the initial invalid model value?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TwzXV/4/

Comment: this is an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1412 also you can check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/8Fk-Ya6Juzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is reported as a bug. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2841

You can go around this behaviour by creating a directive UNTIL this bug is fixed :)

I got this from [google mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/8Fk-Ya6Juzo)

http://jsfiddle.net/nalberg/XccGJ/

```
app.directive('displayInvalid', function($parse, $filter) {   
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, model) {
        var displayed = false;
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
          // only set once... on initial load
          if(displayed == false && oldValue != undefined){
            displayed = true;
            elm.val(model.$modelValue);
          }
        });
      }
    }
})
```